# How to set Body Mapping Templates for all methods in API Gateway in one time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using aws console and I have a lot of api resources and methods. For each of them I use the same Body Mapping Template:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "body" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))", 
    "httpMethod": "$context.httpMethod",
    "path": "$context.path"
}
```

I tired to copy and paste this template to each api method.
How can I do it in one time? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will completely avoid transformation in API gateway and forward to Lambda with ANY integration.

You can do your conversion out there with common libraries across all lambda.

Hope it helps.